# transforming elements in array from numbers to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, formatting

I have this Array :

```
[{abcd:1, cdef:7},{abcd:2, cdef:8}, {abcd:3, cdef:9}]
```

and I would like to format all the values in it to strings like this :

```
[{abcd:"1", cdef:"7"},{abcd:"2", cdef:"8"}, {abcd:"3", cdef:"9"}]
```

Help please

Comment: Use array.map function

Comment: And the problem is? `Array.prototype.map()`, `Array.prototype.forEach()`, `for...in...`, `Object.prototype.keys()`

Comment: do you need a conversion for only numbers to string or all?

Comment: all would be easier

Comment: WHY do you need this conversion at all?

Comment: `arr.forEach(o => Object.keys(o).forEach(k => typeof o[k] === 'number' && o[k] += ''));`.

Comment: it it part for a json conversion later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map over the array and assign each key value pair to a new object after converting it to a string.

```
const array = [{abcd:1, cdef:7},{abcd:2, cdef:8}, {abcd:3, cdef:9}];

array.map(el => {
  const stringObj = {}
  Object.keys(el).forEach(key => {
    stringObj[key] = el[key].toString();
  })
  return stringObj;
})
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly what i wanted ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
let aItems = [{abcd:1, cdef:7},{abcd:2, cdef:8}, {abcd:3, cdef:9}];

aItems.forEach(oItem => {
    for(let sKey in oItem) {
        if(oItem.hasOwnProperty(sKey)) {
            oItem[sKey] = '' + oItem[sKey];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for quickly answering my question. It was urgent !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` with `Object.entries()` and spread syntax in an object literal. The `String` function will convert the value for you.

```js
var data = [{abcd:1, cdef:7},{abcd:2, cdef:8}, {abcd:3, cdef:9}];

var result = data.map(o =>
  ({...Object.entries(o).map(([k,v]) => ({[k]:String(v)}))})
);

console.log(result);
```

---

Or if you prefer to mutate the original:

```js
var data = [{abcd:1, cdef:7},{abcd:2, cdef:8}, {abcd:3, cdef:9}];

for (const o of data) {
  for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(o)) o[k] = String(v);
}

console.log(data);
```

---

Or using `Object.assign`:

```js
var data = [{abcd:1, cdef:7},{abcd:2, cdef:8}, {abcd:3, cdef:9}];

for (const o of data) {
  Object.assign(o, ...Object.entries(o).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:String(v)})));
}

console.log(data);
```